# How make API calls to OpenStack installed on local machine from outside the network?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openstack, openstack-swift

I installed OpenStack on my local Ubuntu machine and can access the dashboard using a local IP address. I want to get the list of files on the storage from an external Spring Boot application.

I looked into the documentation to authenticate the requests but what should be my REST endpoint. I cannot access 10.0.0.x from outside the network so how do I expose my local OpenStack to accept API calls from outside the local network?

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously there is not way to achieve that from what you describe -- `I cannot access 10.0.0.x from outside the network`.

I think you should have a **[NGINX Reverse Proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)** server which could connect to the private network(10.0.0.x) and the public network(outside the network).

Comment: I was thinking more like using my router for port forwarding and the endpoint would be routerIP:port_on_which_openStack_isaccepting_API_request

Comment: Could you router connect to private and public network?